# How to get 16:9 aspect ratio output with powerdot document class?

Tags: paper-size, presentations, powerdot

I am using the `powerdot` document class for generating a presentation file. Unfortunately it outputs a 4:3 document with the default `paper=screen` option. Is there some way to generate a true 16:9 aspect ratio document?

Following the documentation I also tried the `paper=smartboard` option but this has two problems:

- it is not really 16:9, but more like 14:9
- it uses a much larger page height making the text smaller

It would be great to have a paper with a similar height as the original `screen` paper (8.25in) with an resulting aspect of 16:9.

Comment: if you're strongly attached to `powerdot`, you might be in a bit of a pickle. AFAIK 16:9 is unsuppported. you might have better luck with `beamer`

Comment: Not the best solution but you can make your own class as a duplicate of `powerdot` and replace `\def\pd@tempa{papersize={900pt,1440pt}}` with `\def\pd@tempa{papersize={594pt,1056pt}}` (use `paper=smartboard` also)

Comment: You might also look at pdfscreen and texpower.

Comment: @alwaysask: After some different tests this is what I settled to. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can duplicate `powerdot` and create a custom class `my-powerdot` by replacing

```
\def\pd@tempa{papersize={900pt,1440pt}}
```

with

```
\def\pd@tempa{papersize={594pt,1056pt}}
```

which is a 16:9 ratio for `paper=smartboard` option (594 pt =  8.25 inches).